# Python Indexerror: pop from empty list

Tags: python, proxy, python-multithreading

```
def check_proxy(self, proxy):
    urllib2.install_opener(
        urllib2.build_opener(
            urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https': 'http://%s' % proxy})
            )
        )

    try:
        urllib2.urlopen(self.proxy_test_url, timeout=self.proxy_timeout)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def run(self):
    switch = False
    while self.servers and self.proxies:
        self.cron['servers_left'] = len(self.servers)
        self.cron['proxies_left'] = len(self.proxies)

        line = self.servers.pop(0)
        ip = line.split(':')[0]
        port = line.split(':')[1]

        if not 'proxy' in locals() or switch == True:
            proxy = self.proxies.pop(0)

        if not self.check_proxy(proxy):
            proxy = self.proxies.pop(0)
            continue

        switch = False

        if self.check(ip, port, proxy) == False:
            self.server.insert(0,line)
            switch = True


c = checker(inn, valid, server, proxies)
for t in range(thread_count):
    threads.append(my_thread(c))

print 'Starting threads 1 - %s.' % str(thread_count)

for t in threads:
    t.start()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

This is the part of the script that uses .pop, the list isn't empty for sure.. It's wierd, if it's say under 1000 proxies, it'll throw error, so I duplicate the 1000 proxies to 2000 and it runs but then once it uses so many it then throws the error list is empty? When it isn't, I'd like to loop my proxies but the main problem atm is it should go from first proxy to end proxy and finish task..

instead it claims the list is empty with

Indexerror: pop from empty list.

Comment: Can you somehow print or log `self.servers` right before the `pop` call so we can see what is contained in it?

Comment: You have two pops from `self.proxies` without checking in between if it is empty. Looks like it would be empty occasionally.

Comment: Note: Instead of `ip = line.split(':')[0]` and `port = line.split(':')[1]` you could do `ip, port = line.split(':')[0:2]`

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan it just outputs whether server is live or not, so if server is live print 'active', if server is dead print 'dead'

Comment: @LucyBeale I mean `print(repr(self.servers))` to find out what's actually stored in there. If a string was stored there you'd be getting a different error, so it can't be that it contains either `"active"` or `"dead"`.